# Why can't I map Account Number on Lead Conversion

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

On the [Map Lead Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm) screen I don't see the option to set the `Account Number`.

This seems like it should be doable...

Am I missing something?

The only work around I can think of is to set a different field and then have a workflow populate the account number on creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map to any standard field. You will indeed need to come up with an alternative solution. As the help topic you pointed out states:

> For each **custom** lead field, choose a **custom** account, contact, or opportunity field into which you want the information inserted when you convert a lead. *(Emphasis added)*

You can use a workflow rule, process builder, etc. to copy the field value from a custom field to the standard one, if you desire..

Comment: I actually don't think you can use process builder, as you can't seem to access the account record from the lead.  Thanks for the explination

Comment: @NSjonas No, you create a custom account field, map to the custom field, then use the process builder/workflow to copy from your custom account field to the standard account field.

Comment: are there any abnormalities in the trigger execution order?  I have a `after insert` trigger that relies on the Account Number being set.  Looking at the logs from ConvertLead, it doesn't appear that workflows aren't even being executed...

Comment: @NSjonas You'll want to see the [triggers and order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) page, but yes, your account before insert trigger runs before workflow rules or process builder. It might be better to just update your trigger to copy the value instead.